# How can I create an identical smaller shape inside of a shape

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, rigging

Not quite sure how to phrase this properly. I created a mesh of a human and textured it with skin and with anotomical muscle meat. I need the muscle one to be a tiny bit smaller so that it will not poke through. Regular object mode scaling does not work because it scales everything inward making the gap between the legs smaller. I tried solidify on the skin to make it slightly thicker, but when I get it thick enough so that it doesn't stick through when it is deformed by the armature, the eyes end up getting puffy.

[image: Puffy eyes (with solidify)]
Puffy eyes (with solidify)

[image: Without solidify, the mesh peaks through a bit.]
Without solidify, the mesh peaks through a bit when I armature it.

The weights are copied between the two meshes and the meshes are identical copies. For some reason, when it isn't deformed with armature, only the skin shows and not the muscle.
I'm appreciative for suggestions for fixing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do this and get a decent result. Some editing was still needed, but this is the best result I have obtained for this on a complex mesh.

1. Go to modifier tab
2. Add shrinkwrap modifier
3. Set snap mode to "inside"
4. Play with offset as needed
5. Once you get a satisfactory/close result, click on the arrow icon of your deform and click apply to have it converted from a modifier to real geometry.
6. Manually edit as needed to repair any mesh defects.

Answer (score 0):

if your muscles are all separated parts you could try it with scaling with individual origins. Maybe this is what you want.

Looks like this:

[image]